# Razor support of generic extension methods

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

With regards to the Razor view engine, say I want to render `Html.TextBoxFor<SomeModel>(i => i.Name)`, it doesn't seem that the inline syntax works as in:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor<SomeModel>(i => i.Name)
```

This doesn't seem to work because it interprets the generic as an HTML tag.  I could use a code-block approach, but then what's the best approach to output the content?  The HTML string returned from this method, do I response.write it, or is there a syntax for it, or what's the approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are four ways that I've found to get razor to explicitly parse (as opposed to trying to work out what to do):

```
 - @(some code)  (this is the method used by @Matt Hamilton) 
 - Html.Raw("some encoded text") 
 - <text>Some encoded text</text>
 - @@
```

Only the first of these would work here.

There is [a walkthrough on PluralSight](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-mvc3-intro) in the Razor and ASP.NET MVC 3.0 | Intermingling code and markup section, on this exact subject.

Comment: I figured @() would work, but the thing is Html.TextBoxFor<> returns a string, does it get auto rendered if it sees a string?  That was what I was wondering, maybe a combo of @() with Html.Raw...

Comment: Yes. The @() simply forces razor to treat the block as code, and not attempt to work out what is code and what is html (ie like wrapping <% %> round it previously).  As all razor code is html encoded by default if the code output contains html (like a richtext field containing some markup) it will be emitted.  So, yes, to get the  string and maintain the encoding it might be simpler to use Html.Raw() as well.

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
@(Html.TextBoxFor<SomeModel>(i => i.Name))
```

Do parentheses help?

Comment: +1 I think this will be one of the biggest early gotchas of mvc 3

Comment: Yes it does, that was what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure if Razor would just explicitly take a string returned from a method and render it...  or if I had to.  I guess I should have just tried it :-)  Maybe in combination with Html.Raw as @melvin suggests.